# Firestore allow read if collection name matches

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to implement what I thought was a basic security rule in Cloud Firestore, namely to allow read access to a specific collection.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{collectionName}/documents {
      match /{document=**}{
      allow read : if collectionName=="metadata";
      }
  }
}
```

so in the rules playground, the query for `/metadata/status` gets denied, however, if I switch the operator to `!=` instead of `==`, it allows any query for any collection, not just the ones that aren't `metadata`. Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The placement of that wildcard is incorrect. The `collectionName` would be name of the database which is `(default)` *for default* database and hence `"(default)" == "metadata"` returned false. Try the following rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{collectionName}/{doc}{
      allow read : if collectionName == "metadata";
    }
  }
}
```

Here `collectionName` would be name of collection being accessed.

---

This rule however will be applied for all collections. If you want to add that rule for 'metadata' collection only then you can add a separate rule for that:

```
match /metadata/{doc} {
  allow read: if true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set a rule on only a specific document, E.g: Inbox:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow public read access, but only authorized users can write
    match  /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true
      allow write: if (request.auth.uid != null);
    }
      match  /Inbox/{document=**} {
      allow read,write: if true
    }
  }
}
```